# iptables drop INPUT packets if they're not from my country

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, iptables, vps

I'm thinking about adding rules to my iptables (Debian system) INPUT chain in my VPS that would only accept packets coming from my home country (my country isn't a huge one). I've found a site that produces exactly this https://lite.ip2location.com/ip-address-ranges-by-country and I've just been thinking, is it a good idea to do this? I use SSH to access my VPS with RSA keys. The VPS is in the Netherlands.

I guess, concerning questions, I have two.
Firstly, can country specific IP addresses change? For example if my public IP now is 69.34.22.43 and it's based in my country could it later change to another country?
Secondly, if not, could there be any problems with this approach?

I'm thinking of doing this: (-A INPUT country_ip_1 -j ACCEPT); (-A INPUT country_ip_2 -j ACCEPT)....; (-P INPUT DENY)

Also, I should mention that I mainly use public Wi-Fi spots so using just a single static IP (even if my ISP would've given it to me) isn't an option.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Why I want to do this is mainly because I'd like to secure my VPS even more. F.e. if in some freak accident my RSA key would get compromised a person from another country still couldn't get into my VPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are better ways to do what you are wanting.

To your first question. Yes - country IP addresses do change over time.  Generally slowly, and generally be increasing the number of IP added, although it is possible IP addresses will be handed back/transferred to a different area.

I would argue a better approach is to set up a VPN - and only allow SSH connection across the VPN.  This provides much tighter control over who can access your system (is locking it down at tighter then country level) while freeing you up from IP address changes and adding an additional layer of encryption.   This is a fairly standard model used by large companies.  It also means if you do go elsewhere you can still access your system once you have authenticated over a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as an answer mainly because I can get the formatting looking OK.

I made a whitelist like this for certain IP ranges that I connect from because I was sick of random IP addresses trying to connect which were probably portscanning or something

```
# whitelist; block all new inbound connections except from these IP ranges
iptables -N whitelist
iptables -A whitelist -i br0 -j RETURN
iptables -A whitelist -m state ! --state NEW -j RETURN
iptables -A whitelist -s 1.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN #ip range 1: 1.x.x.x
iptables -A whitelist -s 2.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN #ip range 1: 2.x.x.x
# ETC...
iptables -A whitelist -j DROP

iptables -I FORWARD -j whitelist
```

I have used this for at least a year and the IP ranges haven't changed so it works well at least for me and my location. Of course I could not say for sure if any IP address ranges would change for you.

Answer (score 0):

https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/block-ips-countries-geoip-addons/
Here are the instructions

Please read the link above as this only contains the highlights.

Installing Xtables-addons  (You may be able to install this from your package manager and not compile it)

Once our system is upgraded and dependencies are installed, we'll now install the xtables-addons in our machine. To do so, we'll download the latest tarball from the official xtables-addons project site using wget. Once it's downloaded, we'll extract the tarball, then compile and install it in our machine.

```
 wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xtables-addons/Xtables-addons/xtables-addons-2.13.tar.xz
 tar xf xtables-addons-2.13.tar.xz
 cd xtables-addons-2.13
 ./configure
 make
 make install
```

Install GeoIP Database

Next, we'll run a module called xt_geoip that comes with the xtables-addons extension which downloads the GeoIP database from MaxMind and converts it into a binary form recognized by xt_geoip. Once it's downloaded, we'll build it and move them to the required xt_geoip path ie /usr/share/xt_geoip/  .

```
 cd geoip
 ./xt_geoip_dl
 ./xt_geoip_build GeoIPCountryWhois.csv
 mkdir -p /usr/share/xt_geoip/
 cp -r {BE,LE} /usr/share/xt_geoip/
```

After installation is complete this will work

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m geoip --src-cc IN,UN -j DROP
```